# Python Regex help

Tags: python, regex

I would like to use a regex to do the following in Python:

I am given a list of strings such as:
'abc01 - [def02] - ghi03 - jkl04'

Each string will have a different number of items. Some will have brackets around and some will not.

Can someone help me with a regex match that will consist solely of items not in brackets? Dashes and spaces would need to be removed. So for the example above the output would be:
[abc01, ghi03, jkl04]

Thanks

Answer (score 9):

Is regex really the best tool for the job?

```
>>> S = 'abc01 - [def02] - ghi03 - jkl04'
>>> [x for x in S.split(' - ') if not (x.startswith('[') or x.endswith(']'))]
['abc01', 'ghi03', 'jkl04']
```

Answer (score 2):

```
>>> a='abc01 - [def02] - ghi03 - jkl04'
>>> [ i for  i in a.split(" - ") if "[" not in i ]
['abc01', 'ghi03', 'jkl04']
```

Answer (score 0):

The following regex will solve your problem:

```
\b(?<!\[)\w+
```

The Python code is then:

```
for match in re.finditer(r"\b(?<!\[)\w+", input_line):
    item = match.group()
```

Notes:

- `\b` asserts that the item starts at a *word break*, not in the middle of an item
- The *negative lookbehind* `(?<!\[)` asserts that the item wasn't preceded by a `[`
- `\w+` matches an item of at least one consecutive *word character*, as many as possible

Answer (score 0):

From the above description you just need to use findall() to match any sequence of letters and numbers (using the short code \w to match letters and numbers below).

```
>>> import re
>>> re.findall(r'\w+', 'abc01 - [def02] - ghi03 - jkl04')
['abc01', 'def02', 'ghi03', 'jkl04']
```